# How to change npm module for project purpose?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a requirement to change a URL path in the one of the npm module. Can you please suggest the process how to change it in development to production.

Raja K

Comment: can you show me where you want to change? i don't understand ur question

Comment: https://github.com/locize/i18next-locize-backend/blob/master/i18nextLocizeBackend.js

Comment: You can see the https path is hard coded in the npm module. We want to change it

Comment: then, either you have to write a "script" that would change this js file every time package.json modules are installed on your server or what  you can do is  contribute to that project and generate pull request/file issue

Comment: Fork it and use your own package.